# Teamviewer connection error: "Partner did not connect to router", "WaitforConnectFailed"

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, teamviewer

Sometimes I got this error message when trying to connect to a client:

> No connection to partner!
>   Partner did not connect to router.
>   Error Code: WaitforConnectFailed

Both computers are ready for connection according to the information presented in the Teamviewer app windows.
Both computers are running the same version of Teamviewer.

The partner computer cannot connect neither receive connections.

Here's what it looks like on the remote end:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This solve the issue**

For this particular error "Partner did not connect to router" while apparently the partner was ready for connection:

1. Ask the partner to disconnect from the network
2. Ask the partner to restart his/her router (switch off and on)
3. Wait for the router back and ask client to reconnect to the network

Comment: I agree, turning WiFi off and on again solved it for me as well (well, asking them to do it over Skype)

Comment: You may want to consider marking this solved. :)

Comment: But what if it is an unattended computer?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when the DNS resolution on the destination machine was broken; had to connect over SSH, fix DNS settings in /etc/resolv.conf and then connection started to work just fine (system restart wasn't necessary).